# Unable to execute a python file from Katalon

Tags: python, groovy, katalon-studio

I want to execute a python script from Katalon studio.

Below is the code which I am trying to execute from Katalon.

```
def scriptPath = "/Users/amiteshshukla/Documents/Work/highRoads/docgen_validation/docgen_validation.py"
def command = "python $scriptPath"
def result = command.execute().text
println result
return result
```

and this is the python script which I want to execute.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class DocgenValidator:

    print("THis is one of the check***************")

    def __init__(self, baseline_doc_path: str, updated_doc_path: str):

        # Validating inputs
        if not isinstance(baseline_doc_path, str) or baseline_doc_path is None:
            raise TypeError(f" Expected {baseline_doc_path} to be of type str, got {type(baseline_doc_path).__name__}")

        if not isinstance(updated_doc_path, str) or updated_doc_path is None:
            raise TypeError(f" Expected {updated_doc_path} to be of type str, got {type(updated_doc_path).__name__}")

        self.baseline_doc_path = baseline_doc_path
        self.updated_doc_path = updated_doc_path

        self.WORD_NAMESPACE = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
        self.PARA = self.WORD_NAMESPACE + 'p'
        self.TEXT = self.WORD_NAMESPACE + 't'
        print("THis is one of the check***************")
```

But in the output, I am seeing this:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.

2019-05-15 13:48:09.562 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - --------------------
2019-05-15 13:48:09.567 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - START Test Cases/PythonRead
2019-05-15 13:48:10.400 DEBUG testcase.PythonRead                      - 1: scriptPath = "/Users/amiteshshukla/Documents/Work/highRoads/docgen_validation/docgen_validation.py"
2019-05-15 13:48:10.402 DEBUG testcase.PythonRead                      - 2: command = python $scriptPath
2019-05-15 13:48:10.417 DEBUG testcase.PythonRead                      - 3: result = text
2019-05-15 13:48:10.537 DEBUG testcase.PythonRead                      - 4: println(result)

2019-05-15 13:48:10.541 DEBUG testcase.PythonRead                      - 5: return result
2019-05-15 13:48:10.544 INFO  c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - END Test Cases/PythonRead
```

Answer (score 0):

Katalon script mode accepts Groovy/Java code.

Python is not supported. There is [some talk](https://forum.katalon.com/t/suggest-katalon-will-support-python/25197) about it, but the current version (6.1.5) doesn't support it yet. There is a workaround [here](https://forum.katalon.com/t/how-to-use-python-in-katalon-studio/16023) if that helps.

Comment: I am not trying to write code in Katalon using python. Basically, my need is that I want to write a groovy code in katalon which can execute python script. I am almost there. I am able to run the python script by using the above groovy code. Just that only this python script is not running.

Comment: In the linked Katalon forum post, there is a suggestion of doing something like `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python "+ssnDir+"/ssn.py")`.